# Is there a good Java open source OpenID Provider for LDAP?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, openid, single-sign-on

What I am looking for is a Java servlet implementation of an OpenId provider for LDAP ... something I can plug into TomCat, point it at an LDAP directory server, and provide OpenId style authentication from those user accounts in the directory server.

I have been using [OpenID4Java](https://code.google.com/p/openid4java/) for years and it works fine, but it is just an API, and does not provide the user interface required for a complete OpenID provider.

I want to be able to write a large number of small web-based utilities, and allow people SSO access to all of them using OpenID, but these people already have accounts in the directory server, and I do not want to make them create a new password.  They should use the same old password they are used to.

I tried [OpenID-LDAP](https://github.com/adrianheine/openid-ldap), but it is based on PHP.  I am looking for one I can install into TomCat and manage consistently with other JSP based applications.  I looked at [JOIDS](https://code.google.com/p/openid-server/) which seems to have capability to register and manage users, but nothing to link to LDAP.  This excellent [Wiki Page](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995226/Run%20your%20own%20identity%20server) lists other options, like Atlassian Crowd, but I need open source.

I am asking at this time to see if I have missed anything.  If there is nothing, I will probably write one.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using [WSO2 Identity Server](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/) which provides OpenID provider that can be plug in with LDAP and provides UI as well.

Comment: That is a very good suggestion.  It seems to be a very complete implementation, in Java, and open source.  I will check into this.